# Comparing two associative arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, comparison, associative

I started learning Perl last week.

I have an associative array from a file containing 'tokens' - Just a bunch of numbers.
I have another associative array from an SQL Database containing 'tokens'.

I'm wanting to see if any tokens in the file are NOT in the database. However anything I do doesn't seem to work and I've come to the conclusion that I'm just confusing myself.

I'm not sure I *fully* understand associative arrays yet but this is a snippet of my code for the file hash:

```
while($row = <FILE>){
    if($row =~ /^000\E/){
        @tmp=split(/\s+/,$row);     
        if($tmp[1] ne "Unassigned"){
            $tokenfile{$tmp[0]} = $tmp[1] . " " . $tmp[2];
        }
    }
}
```

`$tmp[1]` + `$tmp[2]` are the first and second names. I compare names later on to see if they equal each other. However I want to compare `$tmp[0]` - The token. This is the SQL hash:

```
while(@rows = $sth->fetchrow_array){
    ($name, $passwd, $uid, $gid, $quota, $comment, $gcos, $dir, $shell) = getpwnam("\L$rows[1]\E");
    $gcos =~ s/,.*//;
    if(!defined($gcos)){
        $missing++;
        $tokendb{$rows[0]} = $rows[1];
    }
    else{
        $tokendb{$rows[0]} = $gcos;
    }
}
```

`$rows[0]` is the token.

I assumed I would use two foreach loops such as this:

```
foreach $token (keys(%tokendb)) {
    foreach $token2(keys(%tokenfile)){
        if($token ne $token2){
            print "$token2 NOT IN DATABASE\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But that gives me the result of a *lot* of values that are still in the database.

I'd love some hints as to why this isn't working. Very frustrating as I know it's something so simple but my brain isn't working so well today (Even though it's my 21st Birthday :|).

Comment: What is `\E` in `/^000\E/` supposed to mean? That escape sequence is used to terminate other escape sequences, such as `\Q ... \E`.

Comment: Try this for debugging purposes `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \%tokendb, \%tokenfile;`. Or if this gets too messy, print the values in the loop: `print Dumper "'$token' ne '$token2'"`

Comment: Warning! Warning! If you're learning Perl from a source that still calls hashes "associative arrays" then you're learning from a source that is probably over fifteen years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're iterating over a hash and testing every key individually to see whether one of them is a target value, then you're not taking advantage of the power of hashes:  Lookups.  Try something like

```
foreach $token (keys(%tokenfile)) {
  unless (exists $tokendb{$token}) {
    print "$token NOT IN DATABASE\n";
  }
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach $token (keys(%tokenfile)) {
  if (! exists $tokendb{$token}) {
    print "$token NOT IN DATABASE\n";
  }
}
```

Your nested loop failed because even if a key exists, it doesn't match all the other keys. To do it with a nested loop, it should be:

```
foreach $token (keys(%tokenfile)) {
  $found = 0;
  foreach $token2 (keys(%tokendb)) {
    if ($token eq $token2) {
      $found = 1;
      last;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    print "$token NOT IN DATABASE\n";
  }
}
```

Of course, there's no reason to write it this way, this is just to help you understand how your logic failed.

Comment: You should probably point out that looping over hash keys is redundant in this case. Also, I assume you meant `$found` and `last`, not `found` and `break`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your time. I guess I should of read more into associative arrays as I think I tried *not* to use `exists` and was using `ne`/`eq` instead.